# facebook android SDK unable to determine type of open graph object : book

Tags: android, facebook, share

i am upgrading my android app to the  latest facebook SDk version "v4"
the sdk is offering a better programing model indeed

but when trying to share a story 
using ether the new shareApi or the ShareDialog 
i am getting this error in the callback

unable to determine type of open graph object : book

this is my code

```
private void shareStoryUsingDialog(Activity activity, STORY_TYPE type ,String title, Bitmap bitmap, String peerID, Uri imgURL) {


    ShareOpenGraphAction action ;
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = null;
    ShareOpenGraphObject obj ;

    final SharePhoto photo;
    if(bitmap == null && imgURL != null){
        photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setImageUrl(imgURL).build() ;
    }else{
        photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
    }

    switch (type) {
    case WIN:
        String objty = "og:type" ; 
        obj = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString(objty, "books.book")
        .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
        .putString("og:title", "book title")
        //.putPhotoArrayList("og:image", new ArrayList<SharePhoto>() {{add(photo);}})
        .build();

        action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("books.reads")
        .putObject("book", obj)
        .build();

        content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
        .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
        .setAction(action)
        //.setPeopleIds(peers)
        .build();

        break;
    }

    if(content != null){
        ShareDialog shareDiag = new ShareDialog(activity);
        shareDiag.registerCallback(callbackManager, shareCallback);
        if(ShareDialog.canShow(content.getClass()))
            shareDiag.show(content);
        //ShareDialog.show(activity, content);
        //ShareApi.share(content, shareCallback);
    }
}
```

i found a not very good workaaround
which is force using the web based share dialog 
by replacing this line

```
shareDiag.show(content);
```

with this line

```
shareDiag.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.WEB);
```

Comment: I have implemented a sample app just like you did in this example, and I did not get that error at all. Can you confirm that that the issue persists? I used both ShareApi or the ShareDialog.

Comment: am still working on  it yesterday i tried the same exact code that i was testing before and it worked 

seems like the new SDK is FUUUlll of bugs 
cuz now am unable to attach a local image to a graphStory even the sample apps fail some times

Comment: Maybe you can add more information that you received in the callback to the question. Consider adding the full exception message, stack trace, and the exception's cause (including the cause's message and stack trace).

Comment: thanks for your internist, the error msg that iam  getting is exactly the same as the e question title thats all event the stacktracke of the Facebook error is empty,
 i will post an update to the question

Answer (score 0):

this might sound stupid buy have you declared that exact object with that exact name in your facebook app dashboard? .. I'm having trouble adding an image to an open graph story content too.. I already reported this bug, you can follow it here  : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1391075464548115

Comment: yes i did
event tried multiple Object types and nether worked 
i found an workarround which is using the use of web Share Dialog

,in fact i am  facing the same problem regarding adding a photo to the story , the sdk seems very buggy

Comment: yes it is indeed. Let me know if you fixed this please. Thanks !

Comment: If you are sure that you encountered a bug in the SDK, please file a bug report about it with Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ When you do file a bug, please make sure to include all the necessary steps for Facebook engineers to reproduce the issue.